# What is steadfastsystem.com and why my site load resources from this url?

Tags: url

Today I've noticed that my site (I'm using WordPress) request two connections to steadfastsystem.com

Despite going to the domain and read, I can't find why my site loads it and send information to it.

I'm using Google Adsense as well as Analytics but I don't' think it's related.

Is there a way to find which script and where is it loading from? ([This is my waterfall for instance](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/thegroovecartel.com/nxd1Rzye))

Comment: It says it's a copyright takedown analytics service. I would hazard a guess and say that one of your WordPress plugins is calling it. http://steadfastsystem.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain was used by http://getadmiral.com and was injected by the WordPress plugin Ad Blocker Notify Lite in the latest 2.4 release.
I rolled it out to the previous release and it disappeared.